# Remove Additional Line Break Automatically Created

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code that is incomplete:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Updated by Extendoffice 2017/9/14
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "** We need all of the following to get the control points to set up the Point Files." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "1. Civil CAD drawing with all project grids placed in true coordinates." & vbNewLine & _
              "2. CSV or Text file with Northing, Easting and Elevation coordinates of all marked and confirmed site control locations." & vbNewLine & _
              "3. Job Site: " & vbNewLine & _
              "4. Requester Name: " & vbNewLine & _
              "5. Brief detail of reason for training need(s): "
                  On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "jsmith@test.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "INFORMATION NEEDED TO CREATE SITE AND BUILDING CONTROL"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

On #2 the text is longer and for some reason creating an extra line as seen here:
** We need all of the following to get the control points to set up the Point Files.

1. Civil CAD drawing with all project grids placed in true coordinates.
2. CSV or Text file with Northing, Easting and Elevation coordinates of all marked and confirmed s testing to see if this works
3. Job Site:
4. Requester Name:
5. Brief detail of reason for training need(s):

Can someone please help me correct this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add `<pre>` tags and use HTMLBody

```vb
 xMailBody = "<pre style=""font-family:verdana"">** We need all of the following to get the control points to set up the Point Files." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "1. Civil CAD drawing with all project grids placed in true coordinates." & vbNewLine & _
              "2. CSV or Text file with Northing, Easting and Elevation coordinates of all marked and confirmed site control locations." & vbNewLine & _
              "3. Job Site: " & vbNewLine & _
              "4. Requester Name: " & vbNewLine & _
              "5. Brief detail of reason for training need(s): </pre>"

    With xOutMail
        .To = "jsmith@test.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "INFORMATION NEEDED TO CREATE SITE AND BUILDING CONTROL"
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
```